# Split Lightning Web Component targetConfig Targets

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I have a lightning web component designed for use on `lightning__RecordPage`, `lightningCommunity__Default`, `lightning__FlowScreen`, and `lightning__AppPage` targets.

I need to split off `lightning__FlowScreen` into a separate `targetConfig` in the meta.xml file of the component, to support property types like `String[]` and `Date` that are only available to the `lightning__FlowScreen` context. Currently, I have three of my four targets grouped in a `singleTargetConfig`:

```xml
<targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage,lightningCommunity__Default,lightning__FlowScreen">
```

I have copied the existing properties into two separate targets:

```xml
<targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage,lightningCommunity__Default">

<targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
```

But when I go to deploy the xml file, I return a generic Deploy Error. If I make the error explicit, I receive:

```
"problem": "lightningCommunity__Default is not a flow related target!",
```

I've opened up a ticket with Salesforce Support, who recommends creating a new component and replacing all references, but this component is in use in many different places in flow screens throughout our org.

Any recommendations for splitting a `targetConfig` that was originally specced with multiple targets?